# Source of a jQuery autocomplete being the value of a hidden input variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery's autocomplete, but I'm having problems getting the source to refer to the value of a hidden input on the page.

This is the hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="array_activities" value="[{ label: 'Football', value: '1' }, { label: 'Tennis', value: '2' }, { label: 'Running', value: '3' }]">
```

And this is the javascript:

```
$("#search").live("focus", function (event) {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        close: function( event, ui ) { area_input(); },
        source: $("#array_activities").val()
    });
});
```

But nothing auto-completes.

If I change the value of the source option to explicitly be the value of the hidden input (i.e. replace `'$("#array_activities").val()'` with

`'[{ label: 'Football', value: '1' }, { label: 'Tennis', value: '2' }, { label: 'Running', value: '3' }]'),`

it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parse it before assigning it as a source**

```
source: JSON.parse( $("#array_activities").val() )
```

As the source is expected to be an `array of objects` and `not a string`.

**EDIT**

`JSON` string with single quotes is not a valid syntax. All the properties have to be enclosed in double quotes for a valid syntax.

So change your value to something like this

```
value='[{ "label": "Football", "value": "1" },
      { "label": "Tennis", "value": "2" }, { "label": "Running", "value": "3" }]'
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dU8jR/1/)**

If you want your code to run as is, then you can try with

```
var arr = eval($("#array_activities").val());
```

But using eval is considered a bad practice.

**[For more Info](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)**

Comment: I had tried that but that didn't work. Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dU8jR/.